# How do I get the name of the active user via the command line in OS X?

Tags: macos, command-line

How do I get the name of the active user via the command line in OS X?

Answer (score 314, accepted):

as 'whoami' has been obsoleted, it's probably more forward compatible to use:

```
id -un
```

Comment: In what sense is 'whoami' obsoleted?  Who has declared it obsolete?

Comment: @Jonathan: The man page for `whoami` on Leopard confirms that it has been replaced by `id`.

Comment: Agh! Why are they changing something that has been around since the dawn of time?

Comment: whoami to say?   <boom-chacka>

Comment: 12 years later and both `whoami` and `id` still work on my macOS Big Sur 11.3.1 system. I haven't knowingly installed or configured anything that would have added it back, so maybe it's just still around?

Comment: By the way, `id -gn` displays my group name.

Answer (score 41):

If you'd like to display the full name (instead of the username), add the `-F` flag:

```
$ id -F
Andrew Havens
```

Comment: -F is an illegal option in Mavericks - when did this first begin working?

Comment: '-' 0r z gia b0rah

Answer (score 32):

I'm pretty sure the terminal in OS X is just like unix, so the command would be:

```
whoami
```

I don't have a mac on me at the moment so someone correct me if I'm wrong.

NOTE - The `whoami` utility has been obsoleted, and is equivalent to `id -un`. It will give you the current user

Answer (score 20):

[whoami](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/whoami.1.html)

**EDIT**

The whoami utility has been obsoleted by the id(1) utility, and is equivalent to `id -un`.  The command `id -p` is suggested for normal interactive use.

Answer (score 14):

Via [here](http://forums.macosxhints.com/archive/index.php/t-91484.html)

Checking the owner of /dev/console seems to work well.

`stat -f "%Su" /dev/console`

Comment: This works great if you are ssh'ed into a machine and want to see if a user is logged on locally. If they are not, the command will return "root".

Comment: This is an underrated answer. You cannot do `sudo id -un` to get the name of the logged-in user (as `id` is more "what is the id of the user who's running the `id` command). That makes `id` great for "what user is running my script", but not for admin duties.

Answer (score 6):

There are two ways-

```
whoami
```

or

```
echo $USER
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the `logname` command from the BSD General Commands Manual under Linux or MacOS to see the username of the user currently logged in, even if the user is performing a `sudo` operation. This is useful, for instance, when modifying a user's crontab while installing a system-wide package with sudo: `crontab -u $(logname)`

Per `man logname`:

```
LOGNAME(1)

NAME
    logname -- display user's login name
```

Comment: This is definitely the cleanest and easiest solution. It works no matter what user is executing the command.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to know who's currently logged in to the system:

```
$ w
 15:56:14 up 5 days, 20:58,  6 users,  load average: 0.43, 0.53, 0.50
USER     TTY        LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
me       pts/2     Fri19    1:03m  0.98s  0.98s -/bin/bash
me       pts/3     09:55    6:00m  0.43s  0.43s /bin/bash
me       pts/5     15:56    0.00s  0.23s  0.00s w
```

(This is from a Linux system; the formatting on OS X may be slightly different, but the information should be about the same.)

There may be multiple login sessions; UNIX is designed to be a multi-user system, after all.

Answer (score 3):

The question has not been completely answered, IMHO.  I will try to explain: I have a crontab entry that schedules a bash shell command procedure, that in turn does some cleanup of my files; and, when done, sends a notification *to me* using the OS X notification center (with the command `osascript -e 'display notification ...`).  If someone (e.g. my wife or my daughter) switches the current user of the computer to her, leaving me in the background, the cron script *fails* when sending the notification.

So, *Who is the current user* means *Has some other people become the effective user leaving me in the background*?  Do `stat -f "%Su" /dev/console` returns the current **active user** name?

The answer is yes; so, now my crontab shell script has been modified in the following way:

```
...
if [ "$(/usr/bin/stat -f ""%Su"" /dev/console)" = "loreti" ]
then /usr/bin/osascript -e \
  'display notification "Cleanup done" sound name "sosumi" with title "myCleanup"'
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

getting username in **MAC terminal** is easy...

I generally use `whoami` in **terminal**...

For example, in this case, I needed that to install **Tomcat Server**...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Define 'active user'.

If the question is 'who is the logged in user', then 'who am i' or 'whoami' is fine (though they give different answers - 'whoami' reports just a user name; 'who am i' reports on terminal and login time too).

If the question is 'which user ID is the effective ID for the shell', then it is often better to use 'id'.  This reports on the real and effective user ID and group ID, and on the supplementary group IDs too.  This might matter if the shell is running SUID or SGID.

Answer (score 1):

You can also retrieve it from the environment variables, but that is probably not secure, so I would go with Andrew's answer.

`printenv USER`

If you need to retrieve it from an app, like Node, it's easier to get it from the environment variables, such as

`process.env.USER`.

Answer (score 0):

you can open terminal and write down following command:

```
id -un
```

or

```
whoami
```

This will return your current login username.