# Pass arguments in ruby file for meterpreter?

Tags: ruby, metasploit

I have this .rb file with the command:

```
cd /users/someusername/documents
```

The problem is that instead of "someusername", i would like to get the actual username of my target pc(which is my own pc used for penetration testing).

Update:
Just to clarify: I am running the resource script using the :resource: command from my meterpreter session. I guess this is different from running meterpreter scripts since the way I am doing it, runs every line in the file as a meterpreter command.
Any idea of how I could get the target's username from the file then? I mean the ENV does not seem to work with this approach. I am open for all suggestions!

Thanks! Much appreciated!

Comment: It's in the `ENV` variable (try `ENV['USER']`  or `ENV['USERNAME']`)

Comment: Thanks man! Could you give me an example of that with my cd command? I do not really know how to set it up. :))

Comment: because this does not seem to work: cd /users/ENV['USER']/documents

Comment: I don't know what your code looks like, but you can try this: `"cd /users/#{ENV['USER']}/documents"`

Comment: Thanks for your time. I have a .rb file and when i run it in metasploit, it simply runs the commands given in the rb file and every command is separated by line. I then tried to write "cd /users/#{ENV['USER']}/documents" in the file but then when i did "resource cdfile.rb" in my meterpreter session, it tried to cd "users/#{ENV['USER']}/documents" instead of the username that should be returned from the ENV?

Comment: Here is the output when running it: meterpreter > resource cdme.rc
[*] Reading /root/cdme.rc
[*] Running cd c:/users/#{ENV['USER']}/documents

[-] stdapi_fs_chdir: Operation failed: The system cannot find the path specified.

meterpreter > Interrupt: use the 'exit' command to quit

Comment: What does `p ENV['USER']` display when you put it at the beginning of your script?

Comment: after putting it in my script and after i called the script using the :resource: command in my meterpreter session, it simply tried to run p ENV['USER'] as a command, which of course lead to an error :( and it said "unknown command: p"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Direct shortcut (if available)

If `someusername` is the current user name,  you could use :

```
cd ~/documents
```

## Environment variable (if available)

```
current_user = ENV['USER']
cmd = "cd /users/#{current_user}/documents"
```

## Getting username with id

This [command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1105078/6419007) could help you :

```
current_user = %x(id -un).chomp
cmd = "cd /users/#{current_user}/documents"
```

## Yet another try

According to this [post](https://community.rapid7.com/community/metasploit/blog/2011/12/08/six-ways-to-automate-metasploit), resource files seem to be [ERB](http://www.stuartellis.name/articles/erb/) files.
So you could write :

```
cd /users/<%= ENV['USER'] %>/documents
# or
cd /users/<%= %x(id -un).chomp %>/documents
```

Comment: Yeah i know that that is the shortcut on a mac but when i try to do it from meterpreter, this happens: that is does not exist?

Comment: great thanks! But can these things be used in .rb files called using the :resource: command from meterpreter? Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, non of it works for me... Since the rb files are being called from the resource command, it runs every line as a command, which probably also is why your answer is not working for me.. Any suggestions?

Comment: Documentation is all over the place on resource files, with no clear indication of what's possible and what the expected Ruby syntax is. I added yet another possibility

Comment: Wow I really appreciate your time! But it says: "stdapi_fs_chdir: Operation failed: 1" :(

Comment: Yeah, it was possible for me to get the environment for 'user' and then using that in the cd command as the username. I just had to use another way of scripting than what I attempted at first :) So thank you