# What is the variable username on a MAC

Tags: vba, macos, applescript

I recorded a macro to save a workbook to the desktop on a Mac, but I can't figure out how to make the username a variable name similar to VBA environ$(username)

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="/Users/username/Desktop/test.xls", _
```

FileFormat:=xlExcel8, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", _
ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104972/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-the-active-user-via-the-command-line-in-os-x

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the name of the active user via the command line in OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104972/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-the-active-user-via-the-command-line-in-os-x)

Answer (score 0):

In AppleScript you can set a variable, e.g. `theFilename` to the path of the users Desktop and the filename as, e.g.:

```
set theFilename to POSIX path of (path to desktop as string) & "filename.xls"
```

Have look at AppleScript documentation for [`path to (folder)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW19), for all of the various locations this form is applicable.

If it's just the users name you want:

```
set theShortUserName to short user name of (get system info)
```

Or

```
set theShortUserName to do shell script "printf $USER"
```