# Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'

Tags: node.js, npm, permission-denied

What might be causing the error `Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'`?

```
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/macbookmd101/.npm/_logs/2018-02-21T16_26_08_421Z-debug.log
```

Comment: See the official guide by NPM on how to resolve this: https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally

Comment: Could you change the selected right response? It is completely wrong (even with nearly 1K votes) and dangerous as well. People copy&paste without knowing what they are really doing so don't lead them to mess up the system.

Answer (score 1126, accepted):

Change your file permissions... Like this

First check who owns the directory

```bash
ls -la /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

it is denying access because the node_module folder is owned by root

```bash
drwxr-xr-x   3 root    wheel  102 Jun 24 23:24 node_modules
```

so this needs to be changed by changing root to your user but first run command below to check your current user [How do I get the name of the active user via the command line in OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104972/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-the-active-user-via-the-command-line-in-os-x)

`id -un` OR `whoami`

Then change owner

```bash
sudo chown -R [owner]:[owner] /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

OR

```bash
sudo chown -R ownerName: /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

OR

```bash
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

Comment: There were cases when adding sudo in command also did not worked. This worked for me and should be accepted answer.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer due to permissions of other files that you own accessing the globally installed npm modules.

Comment: Great answer. I had forgotten this! Adding to the calls for this to be accepted answer. Using sudo should be discouraged. For Linux and MacOS this is the best approach IMO assuming one primary user of node.js on that machine. Might want to show novices how to change all child subdirectories as well since they may get cascading permission problems.

Comment: My company uses Microsoft Active Directory Single Sign On. So the group name has slashes in it and a space in it. Which makes this a little harder to do. The command I used was `sudo chown -R myuser:Company\\Domain\ Users /usr/local/lib/node_modules`. To properly list the group name I did `id -gn myuser`.

Comment: This was helpful but when I run the command to change the owner I got `illegal group name`. So I changed the command to `sudo chown -R ownerName: /usr/local/lib/node_modules` and it worked.

Comment: Although thats the right answer, I have encountered this issue multiple times and the better solution is to use nvm. this way you won't need to change files owner using `chown`. 
https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

Comment: still getting the same issue, does it need system restart ?

Comment: Instead of chaning the permission, its recommended in the docs to install npm with nvm. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/59575266/2311074

Comment: command :     sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules    Works for me fully.

Comment: For me the 2nd command `sudo chown -R ownerName: /usr/local/lib/node_modules
` works

Comment: I believe the first command should be changed to `ls -la /usr/local/lib/ | grep node_modules` for clarity. 

I ran the original command, `ls -la /usr/local/lib/node_modules`, and encountered a list of files and folders with permission and access information for different user groups, but the onscreen output were for the contents of the node_modules folder itself. The `drwxr-xr-x   3 root    wheel  102 Jun 24 23:24 node_modules` output is not returned from the current command.

Would you kindly update it for future readers?

Comment: This does not solve the problems. You should really follow the official hints to solve it on https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally#manually-change-npms-default-directory

Comment: The best way to solve this issue (as the solution may vary from one device to another) is to read carefully the error in order to figure out which folder needs write access.

In my case, I had to give /usr/local/lib and /usr/local/bin permissions.

Comment: **STOP**  Do https://stackoverflow.com/a/55274930/234110 instead of messing with permissions of `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.4 I was trying npm install -g @angular/cli but sudo npm install -g @angular/cli worked for me

Comment: Also do not understand why I should give access to system wide folder if I want to install modules locally for the project!

Comment: I used the ````id -un```` to check the name of the active user. Once I found out it's not root, I didn't proceed to change the owner. I just put sudo before I run the npm command and then enter my password. My installation went smoothly.

Comment: If we ran `sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules` how do we revert it?

Comment: @Stephanieraymos `sudo chwon -R  root :wheel /usr/local/lib/node_modules`

Comment: @okandas chown: :wheel: No such file or directory

Comment: What if another user also needs that access?

Comment: @Stephanieraymos typo, `sudo chwon -R  root:root  /usr/local/lib/node_modules`

Comment: You might want to check for global `node_modules` location first using `npm root -g`, because it's not always in `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`

Answer (score 541):

To minimize the chance of permissions errors, you can configure npm to use a different directory. In this example, you will create and use a hidden directory in your home directory.

Back up your computer.
On the command line, in your home directory, create a directory for global installations:

```bash
mkdir ~/.npm-global
```

Configure npm to use the new directory path:

```bash
npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
```

In your preferred text editor, open or create the `~/.profile` file and add this line:

```bash
export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
```

On the command line, update your system variables:

```bash
source ~/.profile
```

To test your new configuration, install a package globally without using `sudo`.

---

Source: the NPM [website](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally#manually-change-npms-default-directory).

Comment: This is the least destructive option in my opinion. It's also [recommended in the npm website](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally#manually-change-npms-default-directory).

Comment: Alternatively, if you don't want to do `npm config set prefix` (especially if you're writing a non-root installer), you might want to override the `PREFIX` env var or provide the `--prefix` option, both of which equivalent to `npm config set prefix`. (not sure which overrides which)

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. In my opinion, this answer makes the least room for destructive errors and is very simple to understand and implement.

Comment: The recommended solution on the NPM website is actually "Reinstall npm with a node version manager". This is an alternative.

Comment: To create `.profile` type `touch .profile`. To then open it in mac type `open .profile`. And `source ~/.profile` is  a command by itself.

Comment: if you're using `zsh` you can use `~/.zshrc` instead of `~/.profile`

Comment: For me worked if I to added to '.bash_profile'

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with a `nvm` install: `Your user’s .npmrc file (${HOME}/.npmrc) has a `globalconfig` and/or a `prefix` setting, which are incompatible with nvm. Run `nvm use --delete-prefix v16.18.1 --silent` to unset it.`

Answer (score 142):

I tried the solution of the answer given by @okanda but it didn't work for me.

However it worked perfectly when I did it for several folders like mentioned in this thread: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9676#issuecomment-464857493

```bash
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/bin/
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/share/
```

Comment: I have in the output: `dest: '/usr/local/bin/.npm-uJtxIR1m'`. So should I chown /usr/local/bin because the .npm.. seems a dynamic file/folder?

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/developing/tips#resolving-permission-errors

Comment: straight forward.
worked for me

Answer (score 91):

All you need to do is to add USER to the owner of /local/lib

```bash
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib
```

**EDIT :**

To target precisely and only the node_modules folder, try using this command before using the previous one :

```bash
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

Comment: If future readers do not understand permissions, then please refer to the official documentation NPM documentation and properly fix the issue. https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally. Specifically, future readers should probably **reinstall npm with a node version manager (recommended)**

Comment: This is pretty straight-forward. It also means you never need to worry about anything in lib again; you own /usr/local/lib.

Comment: This is **not** a good solution at all. By running above `chown` you are at high risk of destroying the permission structure of your entire filesystem.

Comment: This command ruined all of my permissions. Need to recover again all the things.

Comment: To be precise, this is not *adding* an owner. This is *changing* **the** owner, which is far more destructive than just *adding*, and is almost as destructive as `sudo chmod -R 777 /`.

Comment: this is a horrible answer as `/usr/local/` is root for security reasons, and `/usr/local/lib/` doubly so... any hacker with access to your machine will be able to modify standard usr-installed libraries after running this command.

Comment: DO NOT DO THIS!   This is a terrible solution -- not sure why it has 55 upvotes.   You essentially will break permissions on your file system and have to recover them by either reinstalling or mounting your file system on another computer and recovering.

Comment: man this is the best for development machine on Mac I don't need to worry about security issues that's ridiculous its a developers machine

Comment: it just kill my linux, i cannot do a sudo anymore!!!

Comment: The best way to solve this issue (as the solution may vary from one device to another) is to read carefully the error in order to figure out which folder needs write access.

In my case, I had to give /usr/local/lib and /usr/local/bin permissions.

Comment: If we ran `sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib` how do we revert it or change it back?

Comment: it will show `chown: cannot access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules': No such file or directory`

Answer (score 52):

You can install npm through Node version manager or a Node installer. In the [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-node-js-and-npm) it states:

> We do not recommend using a Node installer, since the Node
> installation process installs npm in a directory with local
> permissions and can cause permissions errors when you run npm packages
> globally.

NPM actually [recommends using a Node Version Manager](http://npm.github.io/installation-setup-docs/installing/using-a-node-version-manager.html) to avoid these errors.

Since you have the [permission error](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally), you probably installed npm through a Node installer and now you need to reinstalled it with a nvm (node version manager).

Luckily, this is very simple. You do not even need to remove your current version of npm or Node.js.

All you need to do is

1. Install [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#installing-and-updating).
   For OSX or Linux Node use:

   ```
    curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/<VERSION>/install.sh | bash
   ```

*where `<VERSION>` should be replaced with the latest version*

This creates a nvm folder in your home directory.

Then

2. Install npm and node.js through nvm. To do so, just call

   ```
    nvm install node
   ```

("node" is an alias for the latest version)

Now you can install your package globally without using `sudo` or changing the owner of `node_modules` in `usr` folder.

Comment: thanks for the answer Adam! just wondering what might be some possible complications later on in the build/environment set-up process?

Comment: also to elaborate, for people on `fish`, in order to work properly nvm needs a fish-wrapper https://github.com/FabioAntunes/fish-nvm

Comment: @吖奇说ARCHYSHUō I never heard of any complications when installing node with nvm. And since it is recommended from the official docs, it looks to me like the best way to go :)

Comment: Thanks! I noted that there is a new minor version of NVM, so I guess the command should be `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh | bash` now. Also, I had to close and open Terminal to be able to run `nvm install stable`.

Comment: As a zsh user, I had to do the following. copy the output of 'cat .bashrc | grep nvm' to my .zshrc file. Then nvm was available in my zsh.

Comment: This is the simplest and cleanest answer I've seen. It avoids messing around with folder permissions or forcing it through using "sudo". I think this should be the accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: This resolved my problem regarding `npm install -g mongodb-realm-cli` when the same error as OP occurred.

Comment: Awesome! This should be the accepted answer!

Comment: Should we also add `export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"` into bash?

Comment: @alper where do you got that from?

Comment: @Adam it shows up when I do: `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.0/install.sh | bash` (first step on oyour answer)

Comment: Thanks this resolved my same issues.

Comment: What about `nvm install --lts`? Should get you latest LTS release of `node` and `npm`.

Answer (score 48):

try appending **sudo** before whatever command you are trying.

like this : **sudo npm install**

Using sudo with a command in Linux/UNIX generally elevates your permissions to superuser levels. In Windows, the superuser account is usually called 'Administrator.' In Linux/Unix the superuser account is generally named 'root'.

The root user has permission to access, modify or delete almost any file on your computer. Normal user accounts can access, modify or delete many fewer files. The restrictions on a normal account protect your computer from unauthorized or harmful programs or users. Some processes require you to perform actions on files or folders you don't normally have permissions to access. Installing a program that everyone can access is one of these actions.

In your case, running the installation command with sudo gives you the permissions of the superuser, and allows you to modify files that your normal user doesn't have permission to modify.

Comment: avoid using sudo while installing npm packages. The deeper you go with such path the harder it will be to fix it afterward. Just change permissions to npm folder as pointed in another answer and live a better life.

Comment: That may work but it will cause continuous issues over time. Avoid this if you don't want to get all kind of permission denied errors. Like denied to npm cache folder, denied to install and so on.

Comment: This answer should be removed as using sudo before installation of packages sets a very dangerous precedent if the user doesn't understand permissions. Please refer to the first answer in which you change ownership of core node location once.

Comment: or at least that's the standard illusion anyways... there are too many ways to gain root access from a user level that haven't been patched after many years, so it's safe to assume any malicious user with access to your machine can easily gain root access through any poorly secured application you have installed.

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/developing/tips#resolving-permission-errors

Comment: This answer is dangerous.  "Just use sudo", rather than find8ing the underlying problem is a very very bad habit.  Don't be teaching people this.

Answer (score 34):

**If you are experiencing this problem on your Mac, Take the following steps**
First, use the command below to determine who owns this file.

```
ls -la /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

You will find some files below, one of which is listed below.

```
drwxr-xr-x   3 root    wheel  768 May 29 02:21 node_modules
```

Have you noticed that the above file is owned by root? To make changes inside, you must change the path's ownership.

This command can be used to determine who the current user is.

```
id -un (in my case user is Yamsol)
```

and then you can change by calling this command (just replace your user name with ownerName)

```
sudo chown -R ownerName: /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

in my case as you know the user is "yamsol" I will call this command this way

```
sudo chown -R yamsol: /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

that's it.

Comment: it is possible to use `$USER:$USER` to avoid looking up for the user id

Answer (score 28):

It looks like you're running into permission issues. If you are installing `npm-packages` then it might possible that you are getting an `EACCES` error when trying to install a package globally. This means you do not have permission to write to the directories `npm` uses to store global packages and commands.

Try running commands: `sudo chmod u+x -R 775 ~/.npm` and `sudo chown $USER -R ~/.npm` or you can just run any `npm` command with `sudo`, that should get resolve your issue.

If you are installing an `npm-package` locally, then you should be in your local project directory and can try running `sudo npm install <pkg-name>` command to install required package. the purpose of using `sudo` is that it will change your owner permissions so you can make your current user authorized to run `npm` commands.

I'd recommend you to take a look at https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

Answer (score 25):

While installing global packages in **ubuntu**, you need special write permissions as you are writing to the `usr/bin` folder. It is for security reasons.
So, everytime you install a global package, use:

```
sudo npm install -g [package-name]
```

For your specific case, it will be:

```
sudo npm install -g typescript
```

Answer (score 21):

**Be careful** with all responses that change the owner of all directories under */usr/local*
Basically, don't mess the Linux system!!!

Using `sudo` for your local stuff is a really **bad recommendation** as well.

The original link from [www.competa.com](http://www.competa.com) is broken, so this is the original approach from there:

```sh
npm config set prefix ~/.npm

# open your .bashrc (Linux) or .bash_profile (Mac) file for editing:
nano ~/.bashrc # for Linux
# or...
nano ~/.bash_profile # for Mac if you haven't created a .bashrc file

# add these lines:
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/npm/bin"
export NODE_PATH="$NODE_PATH:$HOME/npm/lib/node_modules"

# save the file and then enter this command or logout and login to make the changes take effect:
. ~/.bashrc
# or...
. ~/.bash_profile
```

**Option B:** Use a version manager like [NVM](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)

Answer (score 15):

If it is still not working after giving permissions try running these commands:

```
mkdir ~/.npm-global

npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'

export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH

source ~/.profile
```

and finally test with this command

`npm install -g jshint`

This does not work for Windows.

Comment: If you follow this sequence then third line is non-permanent (will not work after restart) and fourth line is completely irrelevant and do nothing. Please see answer with most score for right solution.

Answer (score 12):

I was trying to install react expo and apart from sudo I had to add --unsafe-perm

like this. This resolves my Issue

```
sudo npm install -g expo-cli --unsafe-perm
```

Comment: @Furquan, Thank you very much...It worked for me after trying different solutions.

Comment: @AzeTech, I am glad it helped :D

Answer (score 9):

Review this carefully:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/developing/tips#resolving-permission-errors

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/{lib/node_modules,bin,share}
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm ~/.npmrc
```

Comment: thank you, its the one comment that help me.

Answer (score 8):

Encountered in CentOS 8 stream

Solution

(1/4) Creating node_modules folder

`$ sudo mkdir /usr/local/lib/node_modules`

(2/4) Own with Current User

`$ sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules/`

(3/4) Own the `bin` folder

`$ sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/bin/`

(4/4) Own the `share` folder

`$ sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/share/`

Answer (score 7):

### For nvm users

```
sudo chown -R $USER /home/bereket/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules
```

**and**

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules/
```

replace `v8.9.1` with your node version you are using.

Comment: This does not worked for me! Still getting the error: npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename 
/home/samuel/.nvm/versions/node/v8.10.0/lib/node_modules/.staging/npm-90fab7c7/node_modules/columnify/node_modules/wcwidth/node_modules/defaults
It appears to be something with /.staging ..that folder does not exist after the attempt of installation. Can you help me with that?

Comment: @Samuel  did u run this command ? `sudo chown -R $USER  home/samuel/.nvm/versions/node/v8.10.0/lib/node_modules`

Answer (score 6):

On my mac similar issue is coming while installing Ionic.

I run the command
`sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/` path you can update as given in error.

Comment: I was inside the folder so I just set this 

sudo chown -R $USER .

Answer (score 5):

Seems like you tried to install a npm package globally rather than locally, as the `man npm install` describes:

> The  **-g**  or  **--global** argument will cause npm to install the package globally rather than locally.

Generally, when you are setting up a npm project (among many others that you could have), it's not a good idea to install packages on Node.js global modules (/usr/local/lib/node_modules), as your the debug log suggested.

Instead of using `-g`, use `--save`, which will automatically save the package as a dependency for your `package.json` file:

Like this:

```
$ npm install express-generator --save

$ cat package.json 
{
  "name": "first_app_generator",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
  "author": "ivanleoncz",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "express-generator": "^4.16.0"
  }
}
```

But as the other answers mentioned, if you're going to use `-g`, you have to use `sudo` (*if your user has sudo privileges: see /etc/sudoers*) when performing `npm install express-generator -g`, but indeed, it's not a good idea, possibly causing permission problems.

**NOTICE**

There are instructions for installing `express-generator` with `-g` option, in order to have the script `express-cli.js` available on the system path, but you can use the locally installed script as well, located at the `node_modules` if your npm project:

```
$ ./node_modules/express-generator/bin/express-cli.js --view=pug myapp
```

> If a message like **/usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory** shows up, install `nodejs-legacy` (Debian/Ubuntu)

IMHO, using `-g` (also using `sudo`) is like **hic sunt dracones**, if you are unsure of the consequences.

For further information:

- [Creating NPM Package (npm init)](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-a-package-json-file)
- [Express.js Generator](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html)

Answer (score 5):

I was able to fix the issue using the following in mac.

```sh
sudo npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli --unsafe-perm=true
```

Comment: WARNING: `--unsafe-perm=true` is a security risk and allows node to run as root

Answer (score 5):

This occurred as a result of `npm` not being able to access your global `node_modules` directory locally, running

```
sudo chown -R Name: /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

e.g.

```
sudo chown -R developerayo: /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

fixes the issue, now you can run the command you ran again.

Answer (score 5):

For those of you still unable to fix the problem after using the above mentioned solutions. Try this

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(npm config get prefix)/{lib/node_modules,bin,share}
```

That should do the trick, cheers!

Answer (score 5):

It is work 100%

sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(npm config get prefix)/{lib/node_modules,bin,share}

Answer (score 5):

Below command worked for me:

```
sudo npm install -g appium --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this command to install `npm` **as the sudo user:**

```
sudo npm install -g create-react-app
```

**instead of** 
npm install -g create-react-a pp.

Comment: quoting @Lukas- using sudo while installing npm packages. The deeper you go with such path the harder it will be to fix it afterward. Just change permissions to npm folder as pointed in another answer and live a better life.

Comment: Not a good idea. I would suggest against it. You open another can of worms this way.

Answer (score 3):

Simply you can change the owner or just use sudo before you command like this

`sudo chown -R [owner]:[owner] /usr/local/lib/node_modules` (*change owner*)

or

```
sudo npm install -g json-server
```

that's it.

Answer (score 3):

You need the permission of superuser levels to install React. In Linux/Unix the superuser account is generally named 'root'.

To get superuser privilege just run the following command on your terminal:

```
sudo -i
```

and then simply run the command to install React:

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

However, the reactjs team encourages us to use the following command instead of installing a global package.

```
npx create-react-app app_name
```

Comment: Using sudo is a risky proposition, some packages may be safe but others may set off to do something else and take advantage of the root privileges that you are granting. sudo runs the subsequent commands as superuser

Comment: Some packages like `create-react-app` need root privileges to be installed as global packages; otherwise, you won't able to install it.
However, the reactjs team encourages us to use the following command `npx create-react-app app_name` instead of installing a global package.

Answer (score 3):

**Helped** only this:

```
sudo chown -R ownerName: /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

Answer (score 3):

After long research i understood that nothing is required for mac OS to install angular cli just use `sudo npm install -g @angular/cli` your terminal will prompt password enter your password it will proceed to install cli. It worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules

Answer (score 3):

Similar to POsha's answer but this is what worked for me on ubuntu 19

```
sudo npm i -g ngrok --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```

From this link

https://github.com/inconshreveable/ngrok/issues/429

Answer (score 3):

Just add "sudo" before npm command. Thats it.

Comment: Please don't recommend this as it's an anti-pattern and can mess with future installations

Answer (score 3):

> brew uninstall node

> brew install node

> sudo npm install -g "your_package" --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root

Hopes this helps someone

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get rid of this issue by installing `nvm`, then setting node to latest version.

1. Install `nvm` using `curl` (for latest version go to [nvm.sh](http://nvm.sh))

```sh
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash
```

2. List available node versions

```sh
nvm ls
```

> v10.12.0
>   default -> v10.12 (-> v10.12.0)
>   node -> stable (-> v10.12.0) (default)
>   stable -> 10.12 (-> v10.12.0)
>   …

3. Choose which version of node to use

```sh
nvm use v10.12
```

> nvm is not compatible with the npm config "prefix" option: currently set to ""

4. Run this to unset the option:

```sh
nvm use --delete-prefix v10.12.0
```

After following the commands above, you will be able to install react/angular in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

For linux / ubuntu if the command

`npm install -g <package_name>`

```
npm WARN deprecated superagent@4.1.0: Please note that v5.0.1+ of superagent removes User-Agent header by default, therefore you may need to add it yourself (e.g. GitHub blocks requests without a User-Agent header).  This notice will go away with v5.0.2+ once it is released.

npm ERR! path ../lib/node_modules/<package_name>/bin/..

npm ERR! code EACCES

npm ERR! errno -13

npm ERR! syscall symlink

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules
/<package_name>/bin/..' -> '/usr/local/bin/<package_name>'

npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/<package_name>/bin/..' -> '/usr/local/bin/<package_name>']

npm ERR!   cause:
npm ERR!    { Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/<package_name>/bin/..' -> '/usr/local/bin/<package_name>'

npm ERR!      errno: -13,

npm ERR!      code: 'EACCES',

npm ERR!      syscall: 'symlink',

npm ERR!      path: '../lib/node_modules/<package_name>/bin/..',
npm ERR!      dest: '/usr/local/bin/ionic' },

npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink \'../lib/node_modules/ionic/bin/ionic\' -> \'/usr/local/bin/ionic\'',

npm ERR!   errno: -13,

npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',

npm ERR!   syscall: 'symlink',

npm ERR!   path: '../lib/node_modules/<package-name>/bin/<package-name>',

npm ERR!   dest: '/usr/local/bin/<package-name>' }

npm ERR! 

npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.

npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user

npm ERR! 

npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the

npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running

npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).


npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     /home/User/.npm/_logs/2019-07-29T01_20_10_566Z-debug.log
```

Fix : Install with root permissions

`sudo npm install <package_name> -g`

Comment: I don't want to have to install node scripts with sudo!

Answer (score 2):

Use ***'sudo npm install xyz'*** it will work.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running Linux(ie: Arch)

```
# npm -g install packageName
```

By default this command installs the package under /usr/lib/node_modules/npm and requires root privileges to do so.

### To Allow user-wide installations

To allow global package installations for the current user, set the `npm_config_prefix` environment variable. This is used by both npm and yarn.

```bash
mkdir ~/.node_modules
cat ~/.profile
PATH="$HOME/.node_modules/bin:$PATH"
export npm_config_prefix=~/.node_modules
```

Re-login or source to update changes.

You can also specify the `--prefix` parameter for `npm install`. However, this is not recommended, since you'll need to add it every time you install a global package.

```bash
$ npm -g install packageName --prefix ~/.node_modules
```

So you dont have to chown folder permision

Answer (score 1):

The best way to solve this issue (as the solution may vary from one device to another) is to read carefully the error in order to figure out which folder needs `write` access.

In my case, I had to give `/usr/local/lib` and `/usr/local/bin` permissions.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error while starting the VITE frontend server. I resolved it by adding sudo (since it is some file level permission issue) `sudo npm run dev`. This is not the best/safest solution but the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

I have used sudo, but it didnt solve the problem,
I have fixed the issue by changing the node_modules folder permission,

```
sudo chmod -R 777 node_modules
```

If you want you can replace 777 with any other code if you dont set the permission for all user/group.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and solve it using the command

> sudo npm install -g expo-cli --unsafe-perm

Here in image after running the command

[image]

then run the following commandf to update npm

> npm install -g npm@latest
> [image]

I easily solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I followed some of the answers on this question as I was getting the `Error: EACCES: permission denied` error.

Nothing I did worked except from starting again fresh without node modules.

In the end for me to run the following successful I had to

1. Delete node_modules from my project folder
2. Use nvm to select node version to use
3. Then with no node_modules I ran `npm update --save` successfully

Hopefully this helps someone who was in the same boat as me!

Answer (score -1):

in case anyone want to make the user to have access like a root user check out this https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204012

this supposed to be the best approach if the user account is the owner  of the account

Answer (score -2):

in my case it works i.e i want npm link  so when I hit sudo npm link it works

```
sudo npm install
```

because sudo gives you permissions to superuser levels.
superuser account is usually called 'Administrator.' In Linux/Unix the superuser account is generally named 'root'.

The root user has permission to access, modify or delete almost any file on your computer. Normal user accounts can access, modify or delete many fewer files. The restrictions on a normal account protect your computer from unauthorized or harmful programs or users.

Comment: ***Never*** use `sudo` with `npm`. This can allow potentially malicious packages to take over your computer.

Comment: @GalaxyCat105 Ty for this. Weird because I've been taught during deployment for example, to sudo literally everything on EC2 instances. I'm getting tangled up in some weird permission issues myself. I might need to terminate the instance and start fresh. Do you recommend, from a fresh Ubuntu box for example, only install node, npm, nodemon, nginx, git all as non-root user? If I use sudo, after pulling a git repo for example, and firing off `sudo npm install` I hit EACCES issues in regards to some packages (`bcrypt` for example)...need to get these concepts sorted.

Answer (score -3):

Simple solution for linux users, just add sudo in front of whatever command you're running for npm