# Errors while installing AWS Amplify CLI

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, command-line-interface, aws-amplify

Tried installing the CLI with the command given on the official website, this is the response :

```
npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli
npm WARN deprecated @types/ora@3.2.0: This is a stub types definition. ora provides its own type definitions, so you do not need this installed.
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm WARN @conduitvc/mosca@2.8.3 requires a peer of leveldown@~1.4.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @conduitvc/mosca@2.8.3 requires a peer of ioredis@^1.15.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @conduitvc/mosca@2.8.3 requires a peer of mongodb@~2.1.4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules']
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/local/lib/node_modules\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).
```

I have installed the latest versions of node and npm. Fixing this would be really helpful. TIA

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node\_modules' react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48910876/error-eacces-permission-denied-access-usr-local-lib-node-modules-react)

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I just had to add `sudo` in front of my command line request on my Mac Command Line:

`sudo npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli`

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. What worked for me was:

```
npm uninstall -g @aws-amplify/cli

npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli
```

Make sure your PC is connected to internet connection during all of this. If possible don't minimize the window, wait until everything is properly installed.

Answer (score 0):

Read a blogpost on this similar error and that author suggests to install typescript, which would fix the problem. Followed that advice, installed typescript and installed aws cli and voila! it worked!. No idea how, but it fixed my problem. Curious to know how, if anyone is aware of this please let me know in your answer. TIA

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) /Users/user_name/.config
```