# @ionic/cli not installed after installing

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-cli

I tried to update my ionic cli by removing the ionic package and replacing it with @ionic/cli, but now ionic is no longer a recognized command. Here's what I've tried so far:

Node version - v13.13.0
npm version - 6.13.4

1. exporting prefix to $PATH,

   prefix - /usr/local

   $path - /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:...

   `npm root -g` returns  /usr/local/lib/node_modules
2. brew doctor, brew upgrade node,
3. npm update -g verbose, npm cache clean --force

Every time I run `npm i -g ionic` or `npm i -g @ionic/cli` the installation is successful, but I cannot use ionic commands. Any idea on why this is?

[image: npm install -g @ionic/cli --verbose begin installation]
[image: directory in installation]

Comment: Do you see ionic inside this /usr/local/lib/node_modules?

Comment: yep, the '@ionic folder' is highest order, then cli, then the assets, bin, lib, etc are inside that directory @400_bad_request

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the installation output in verbose?

Comment: I wasn't sure if you wanted me to screenshot the entire output, but I took a picture of what I thought mattered. Is there anything in particular I should look for? @400_bad_request

Comment: Can you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48910876/error-eacces-permission-denied-access-usr-local-lib-node-modules-react