# Global packages successfully installs and works but stops working after terminal restart

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg, expo

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 and I'm finding it really difficult to use global packages like yarn and expo-cli. I successfully installed nodejs but while installing yarn I got this error `EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/lib/node_modules'` and managed to fix it with the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55274930/10798331) and successfully installed yarn. I tested to see if it worked with `yarn --version` and it did, but after closing and re-opening the terminal and doing this `yarn --version` again, I get this `Command 'yarn' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install cmdtest`. If I try installing yarn again, I get this

```
/home/tony/.npm-global/bin/yarn -> /home/tony/.npm-globa/lib/node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn.js
/home/tony/.npm-global/bin/yarnpkg -> /home/tony/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn.js
+ yarn@1.22.4
updated 1 package in 3.177s
```

Notice that yarn doesn't installed but rather updated, I've tried different solutions but still can't fix it. This also happens when I try to install expo-cli. I don't know much about Ubuntu and confused as to what to do now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple restart seemed to fix it. I think one of the solutions I tried fixed the issue but only required a restart.