# Yarn EACCES: permission denied

Tags: yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

I have a workspace setup and ever sense I keep getting permission issues with yarn:

```
error An unexpected error occurred: "EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/code/client/node_modules/cacache/node_modules/mkdirp'".
```

The only solution I have is to delete node_modules on all packages which are part of my workspace, which gets annoying.

Then I run `yarn install` again and everything is fine. Next day I'll come back and face the same issue.

I also have to use sudo to delete node_modules which is strange.

Comment: Take look here ;-) =>  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48910876/error-eacces-permission-denied-access-usr-local-lib-node-modules?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 2):

You can set permission by

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP node_modules
```

or

```
sudo chmod -R u+w /your/project/directory
```

or

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /your/project/directory
```