# ERR undefined while installing airbnb eslint

Tags: node.js, npm, cmd, node-modules, eslint-config-airbnb

```
npx install-peerdeps --dev eslint-config-airbnb
install-peerdeps v3.0.3
Installing peerdeps for eslint-config-airbnb@latest.
npm install eslint-config-airbnb@18.2.1 eslint@^7.2.0 eslint-plugin-import@^2.22.1 eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@^6.4.1 eslint-plugin-react@^7.21.5 eslint-plugin-react-hooks@^1.7.0 --save-dev

ERR undefined
```

idk what's that. Already tried to reinstall node(both LTS and current). The path variable is valid.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I resolved this by explicitly installing the dependent npm packages i.e. `npm install [package]@[version] --save-dev` rather than using the `npx install-peerdeps` shortcut.

The npm package page for [eslint-config-airbnb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-airbnb) details how to list the dependencies using: `npm info "eslint-config-airbnb@latest" peerDependencies`

For version `18.2.1` this gave:

```js
{
  eslint: '^5.16.0 || ^6.8.0 || ^7.2.0',
  'eslint-plugin-import': '^2.22.1',
  'eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y': '^6.4.1',
  'eslint-plugin-react': '^7.21.5',
  'eslint-plugin-react-hooks': '^4 || ^3 || ^2.3.0 || ^1.7.0'
}
```

Log files showing details about the error are located at `~/.npm/_logs/`.

The log file shows that `npx install-peerdeps` chooses `^7.2.0` for `eslint` and `^1.7.0` for `eslint-plugin-react-hooks`. **BUT** the latter `eslint-plugin-react-hooks@^1.7.0` requires `eslint@"^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0"` (according to the log file) hence the error resolving the dependency tree.

I explicitly installed the latest of all packages (i.e. `npm install eslint --save-dev` etc) which installed the following versions (from package.json) which are in line with the dependencies above.

```js
 "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^7.25.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.23.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to run:

```
(
  export PKG=eslint-config-airbnb;
  npm info "$PKG@latest" peerDependencies --json | command sed 's/[\{\},]//g ; s/: /@/g' | xargs npm install --save-dev "$PKG@latest"
)
```

Instead, as stated in the [official docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-airbnb)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My problem was that I had permissions erros when I was installing global packages. First I tried to change the permissions for my node_modules but that didn't worked for me, so I just configured npm to use a different directory.

Here you can see how you can do that:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55274930

Answer (score 0):

1. First run `npm info "eslint-config-airbnb@latest" peerDependencies` to check the dependency versions
2. Use the versions for your own "npm install string" ex. `npm i -D eslint@7.2.0 eslint-plugin-import@2.22.1 eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y eslint-plugin-react@7.21.5 eslint-plugin-react-hooks@^4`