# I need help trying to install nestJS on my MacBook

Tags: installation, terminal, nestjs

[image]

I am having issues trying to install nestJS for my MacBook and this error keeps popping up in my terminal when I use $ npm install -g @nestjs/cli . Am I doing something wrong or am I not putting this command line in the right place? Please help :)

Comment: try to run terminal in administrator mode and try it again

Comment: Please put your codes instead of including a screenshot of them

Comment: @ZubairSaif it worked! Thank you! I just used the installation command line from nestJS and put sudo in front of it and it worked.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Running the command as `sudo` is only a temporary solution as you generally want to have access to this directory as a regular user and you will undoubtedly run into future issues working with node_modules.

[The right approach is to change the ownership](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48910876/error-eacces-permission-denied-access-usr-local-lib-node-modules) on this directory so you don't need to use elevated permissions to interact with it.

`sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules`