# I'm getting 'Command not found' when i try to download expo in Ubuntu(Linux)

Tags: linux, npm, command, expo, yarnpkg

[npm install error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwQXX.png)

[yarn install error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uc5W.png)

I keep getting errors whenever i try to download expo in the terminal globally for both npm and yarn. For yarn it installs but isn't downloaded when i check with expo --version

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors. See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're running into permission issues. If you are installing npm-packages then it might possible that you are getting an EACCES error when trying to install a package globally. This means you do not have permission to write to the directories npm uses to store global packages and commands.

Please follow this thread:

[Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48910876/error-eacces-permission-denied-access-usr-local-lib-node-modules)

Answer (score 0):

Try this to install expo client globally:

```
npm i -g expo-cli
```

In order to install it locally run:

```
npm i expo-cli
```

or

```
yarn add expo-cli
```

Comment: I tried it. But unfortunately I keep getting the the same error. But thanks for the help.