# Nodemon install problem. when i am install nodemon in my node js

Tags: node.js, npm, nodemon

saif@saifrakib:~/Project/NodeJs/second-node$ npm install -g nodemon

npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.3.2 (node_modules/nodemon/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib']
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/saif/.npm/_logs/2021-10-22T09_54_02_012Z-debug.log

Comment: can you try providing access to the given folder. use `sudo chmod 777 /usr/local/lib/*`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Change your file permissions.

sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules

Or please check the below link

[Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48910876/error-eacces-permission-denied-access-usr-local-lib-node-modules)