# npm install: Ecacess: permission denied

Tags: reactjs, linux, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to npm install my in react project and am getting this error:
[image]

I've tried sudo chown -R `whoami` to working directory and still no luck..
what else can i do?

Comment: did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/51024493/12536525

Comment: Yes and i still get same error...

Comment: On Windows, you can also have `EACCES` when given file/directory is opened by other process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem when you install packages using `sudo`. That's why you shouldn't install any package using `sudo` keyword.

The solution:
Delete `node_modules` folder. If it says that you don't have permission than delete it directly from folder (not from IDE) or through terminal.

After that install your packages again. This time only `npm i` without sudo.

Comment: Regarding "*you shouldn't install any package using sudo keyword*": For the general case, I disagree, because of the case of globally-installed packages. e.g. the [official `npm` documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/try-the-latest-stable-version-of-npm#upgrading-on-nix-osx-linux-etc) says: "*`npm install -g npm@latest` ... you may need to prefix these commands with sudo, especially on Linux, or OS X if you installed Node using its default installer.*"