# Why am I unable to install expo cli?

Tags: react-native, macos, expo

I have followed the documentation from Expo website, installed NodeJs, git, watachmann, however I m still getting errors when installing Expo cli:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider [not uploading images of code/errors when asking a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also your question looks similar to the following question, does that answer yours? [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node\_modules'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48910876/error-eacces-permission-denied-access-usr-local-lib-node-modules)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, ensure you use the recommended version of [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/). For that, you can use the [n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n) module:

```js
// if you haven't installed it before 
sudo npm install n -g 
//to have the latest stable version
sudo n stable
```

Then delete all your preview installs with `npm` and start over. For `expo-cli`:

```js
sudo npm uninstall --global expo-cli
sudo npm install --global expo-cli
```