# npm ERR! code EACCES， npm install --global yarn met error

Tags: node.js, linux, macos, npm

Mac mini (M1, 2020)

Monterey

Brownie v1.17.2

nodejs v16.13.4

I am learning solidity according to reference(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M576WGiDBdQ&t=25510s).

Node.JS install is fine

when I tried this

```
npm install --global yarn
```

the terminal give the error information

```
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/liwei/.npm/_logs/2022-01-08T12_13_37_765Z-debug.log
(base) liwei@liweideMac-mini-2 com~apple~CloudDocs %
```

I checked the owner of the file ,the owner is root ,should i use sudo?

```
(base) liwei@liweideMac-mini-2 com~apple~CloudDocs % ls -l /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
total 64
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel  9742 10 14 08:49 LICENSE
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel  4190 10 19 06:36 README.md
drwxr-xr-x    9 root  wheel   288 12  1 19:46 bin
drwxr-xr-x    4 root  wheel   128 12  1 19:46 docs
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   145 11 23 14:00 index.js
drwxr-xr-x   77 root  wheel  2464 12  1 19:46 lib
drwxr-xr-x    5 root  wheel   160 12  1 19:46 man
drwxr-xr-x  188 root  wheel  6016 12  1 19:46 node_modules
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel  6007 12  1 19:13 package.json
drwxr-xr-x    3 root  wheel    96 12  1 19:46 tap-snapshots
(base) liwei@liweideMac-mini-2 com~apple~CloudDocs %
```

find this thread ([Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48910876/error-eacces-permission-denied-access-usr-local-lib-node-modules)),changed the owner , stll one file don't change.

```
(base) liwei@liweideMac-mini-2 com~apple~CloudDocs % sudo chown -R liwei: /usr/local/lib/node_modules 
(base) liwei@liweideMac-mini-2 com~apple~CloudDocs % ls -la /usr/local/lib/node_modules              

total 0
drwxr-xr-x   4 liwei  wheel  128  1  8 11:51 .
drwxr-xr-x   4 root   wheel  128  1  8 11:51 ..
drwxr-xr-x   7 liwei  wheel  224 12  1 19:46 corepack
drwxr-xr-x  13 liwei  wheel  416 12  1 19:46 npm
```

what is this 2 dots is?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I had the same problem but I could solve it after seeing a youtube video
use this command:

```
sudo npm install --global yarn
```

Comment: yes sudo also works

Comment: You should [never](https://dev.to/brylie/don-t-use-sudo-with-npm-install-56p9#:~:text=Using%20%22sudo%22%20when%20installing%20NPM,sudo%22%20when%20installing%20NPM%20packages.&text=This%20work%20is%20licensed%20under%20a%20Creative%20Commons%20Attribution%204.0%20International%20License.) use `sudo` with `npm`

Answer (score 7):

reference answer is here
([Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48910876/error-eacces-permission-denied-access-usr-local-lib-node-modules))

This works for me very quick.

To minimize the chance of permissions errors, you can configure npm to use a different directory. In this example, you will create and use a hidden directory in your home directory.

Back up your computer. On the command line, in your home directory, create a directory for global installations:

```
mkdir ~/.npm-global
```

Configure npm to use the new directory path:

```
npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
```

In your preferred text editor, open or create a

~/.profile

file and add this line:

```
export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
```

On the command line, update your system variables:

`source ~/.profile`

To test your new configuration, install a package globally without using sudo