# EACCES permission deny for node version update

Tags: node.js, linux, npm

To run my project, i need to use 14.20.1 version on node. While i am trying to install it i am getting different errors. When i try with ***npm install -g node@14.20.1*** i am getting EACCES error as you can see

```
utku@Linux:~/Zenpepper/zenpepper/newTemplate$ npm install -g node@14.20.1

> node@14.20.1 preinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node
> node installArchSpecificPackage

+ node-linux-x64@14.20.1
added 1 package and audited 1 package in 3.138s
found 0 vulnerabilities

npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! path ../lib/node_modules/node/bin/node
npm ERR! dest /usr/local/bin/node
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/node/bin/node' -> '/usr/local/bin/node'
npm ERR!  [OperationalError: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/node/bin/node' -> '/usr/local/bin/node'] {
npm ERR!   cause: [Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/node/bin/node' -> '/usr/local/bin/node'] {
npm ERR!     errno: -13,
npm ERR!     code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!     syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!     path: '../lib/node_modules/node/bin/node',
npm ERR!     dest: '/usr/local/bin/node'
npm ERR!   },
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!   path: '../lib/node_modules/node/bin/node',
npm ERR!   dest: '/usr/local/bin/node'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/utku/.npm/_logs/2023-08-23T19_33_46_130Z-debug.log
```

So i searched how to install it by another command and i tried installing it by using ***sudo apt-get install nodejs)14.20.1-1chl1~precise1*** but it says that is not exist.

```
utku@Linux:~/Zenpepper/zenpepper/newTemplate$ sudo  apt-get install nodejs=14.20.1-1chl1~precise1
[sudo] password for utku: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package nodejs is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Version '14.20.1-1chl1~precise1' for 'nodejs' was not found
```

Then i tried to see which versions are installable so i used ***npm views node versions*** and i can see that version is there.

```
utku@Linux:~/Zenpepper/zenpepper/newTemplate$ npm view node versions
 
[
  '0.0.0',    '0.1.14',   '0.1.15',   '0.1.16',  '0.1.17',  '0.1.18',
  '0.1.19',   '0.1.20',   '0.1.21',   '0.1.22',  '0.1.23',  '0.1.24',
  '0.1.25',   '0.1.26',   '0.1.27',   '0.1.28',  '0.1.29',  '0.1.30',
  '0.1.31',   '0.1.32',   '0.1.33',   '0.1.90',  '0.1.91',  '0.1.92',
  '0.1.93',   '0.1.94',   '0.1.95',   '0.1.96',  '0.1.97',  '0.1.98',
  '0.1.99',   '0.1.100',  '0.1.101',  '0.1.102', '0.1.103', '0.1.104',
  '0.2.0',    '0.2.1',    '0.2.2',    '0.2.3',   '0.2.4',   '0.2.5',
  '0.2.6',    '0.3.0',    '0.3.1',    '0.3.2',   '0.3.3',   '0.3.4',
  '0.3.5',    '0.3.6',    '0.3.7',    '0.3.8',   '0.4.0',   '0.4.1',
  '0.4.2',    '0.4.3',    '0.4.4',    '0.4.5',   '0.4.6',   '0.4.7',
  '0.4.8',    '0.4.9',    '0.4.10',   '0.4.11',  '0.4.12',  '0.5.0',
  '0.5.1',    '0.5.2',    '0.5.3',    '0.5.4',   '0.5.5',   '0.5.6',
  '0.5.7',    '0.5.8',    '0.5.9',    '0.5.10',  '0.6.0',   '0.6.1',
  '0.6.2',    '0.6.3',    '0.6.4',    '0.6.5',   '0.6.6',   '0.6.7',
  '0.6.8',    '0.6.9',    '0.6.10',   '0.6.11',  '0.6.12',  '0.6.13',
  '0.6.14',   '0.6.15',   '0.6.16',   '0.6.17',  '0.6.18',  '0.6.19',
  '0.6.20',   '0.6.21',   '0.7.0',    '0.7.1',   '0.7.2',   '0.7.3',
  '0.7.4',    '0.7.5',    '0.7.6',    '0.7.7',   '0.7.8',   '0.7.9',
  '0.7.10',   '0.7.11',   '0.7.12',   '0.8.0',   '0.8.1',   '0.8.2',
  '0.8.3',    '0.8.4',    '0.8.5',    '0.8.6',   '0.8.7',   '0.8.8',
  '0.8.9',    '0.8.10',   '0.8.11',   '0.8.12',  '0.8.13',  '0.8.14',
  '0.8.15',   '0.8.16',   '0.8.17',   '0.8.18',  '0.8.19',  '0.8.20',
  '0.8.21',   '0.8.22',   '0.8.23',   '0.8.24',  '0.8.25',  '0.8.26',
  '0.8.27',   '0.8.28',   '0.9.0',    '0.9.1',   '0.9.2',   '0.9.3',
  '0.9.4',    '0.9.5',    '0.9.6',    '0.9.7',   '0.9.8',   '0.9.9',
  '0.9.10',   '0.9.11',   '0.9.12',   '0.10.0',  '0.10.1',  '0.10.2',
  '0.10.3',   '0.10.4',   '0.10.5',   '0.10.6',  '0.10.7',  '0.10.8',
  '0.10.9',   '0.10.10',  '0.10.11',  '0.10.12', '0.10.13', '0.10.14',
  '0.10.15',  '0.10.16',  '0.10.17',  '0.10.18', '0.10.19', '0.10.20',
  '0.10.21',  '0.10.22',  '0.10.23',  '0.10.24', '0.10.25', '0.10.26',
  '0.10.27',  '0.10.28',  '0.10.29',  '0.10.30', '0.10.31', '0.10.32',
  '0.10.33',  '0.10.34',  '0.10.35',  '0.10.36', '0.10.37', '0.10.38',
  '0.10.39',  '0.10.40',  '0.10.41',  '0.10.42', '0.10.43', '0.10.44',
  '0.10.45',  '0.10.46',  '0.10.47',  '0.10.48', '0.11.0',  '0.11.1',
  '0.11.2',   '0.11.3',   '0.11.4',   '0.11.5',  '0.11.6',  '0.11.7',
  '0.11.8',   '0.11.9',   '0.11.10',  '0.11.11', '0.11.12', '0.11.13',
  '0.11.14',  '0.11.15',  '0.11.16',  '0.12.0',  '0.12.1',  '0.12.2',
  '0.12.3',   '0.12.4',   '0.12.5',   '0.12.6',  '0.12.7',  '0.12.8',
  '0.12.9',   '0.12.10',  '0.12.11',  '0.12.12', '0.12.13', '0.12.14',
  '0.12.15',  '0.12.16',  '0.12.17',  '0.12.18', '4.0.0',   '4.1.0',
  '4.1.1',    '4.1.2',    '4.2.0',    '4.2.1',   '4.2.2',   '4.2.3',
  '4.2.4',    '4.2.5',    '4.2.6',    '4.3.0',   '4.3.1',   '4.3.2',
  '4.4.0',    '4.4.1',    '4.4.2',    '4.4.3',   '4.4.4',   '4.4.5',
  '4.4.6',    '4.4.7',    '4.5.0',    '4.6.0',   '4.6.1',   '4.6.2',
  '4.7.0',    '4.7.1',    '4.7.2',    '4.7.3',   '4.8.0',   '4.8.1',
  '4.8.2',    '4.8.3',    '4.8.4',    '4.8.6',   '4.8.7',   '4.9.0',
  '4.9.1',    '5.0.0',    '5.1.0',    '5.1.1',   '5.2.0',   '5.3.0',
  '5.4.0',    '5.4.1',    '5.5.0',    '5.6.0',   '5.7.0',   '5.7.1',
  '5.8.0',    '5.9.0',    '5.9.1',    '5.10.0',  '5.10.1',  '5.11.0',
  '5.11.1',   '5.12.0',   '6.0.0',    '6.1.0',   '6.2.0',   '6.2.1',
  '6.2.2',    '6.3.0',    '6.3.1',    '6.4.0',   '6.5.0',   '6.6.0',
  '6.7.0',    '6.8.0',    '6.8.1',    '6.9.0',   '6.9.1',   '6.9.2',
  '6.9.3',    '6.9.4',    '6.9.5',    '6.10.0',  '6.10.1',  '6.10.2',
  '6.10.3',   '6.11.0',   '6.11.1',   '6.11.5',  '6.12.0',  '6.12.1',
  '6.12.2',   '6.12.3',   '6.13.0',   '6.14.0',  '6.14.1',  '6.14.2',
  '6.14.3',   '6.14.4',   '6.15.1',   '6.16.0',  '6.17.0',  '6.17.1',
  '7.0.0',    '7.1.0',    '7.2.0',    '7.2.1',   '7.3.0',   '7.4.0',
  '7.5.0',    '7.6.0',    '7.7.0',    '7.7.1',   '7.7.2',   '7.7.3',
  '7.7.4',    '7.8.0',    '7.9.0',    '7.10.0',  '7.10.1',  '8.0.0',
  '8.1.0',    '8.1.1',    '8.1.2',    '8.1.3',   '8.1.4',   '8.2.0',
  '8.2.1',    '8.3.0',    '8.4.0',    '8.5.0',   '8.6.0',   '8.7.0',
  '8.8.0',    '8.8.1',    '8.9.0',    '8.9.1',   '8.9.2',   '8.9.4',
  '8.10.0',   '8.11.0',   '8.11.1',   '8.11.2',  '8.11.3',  '8.11.4',
  '8.12.0',   '8.13.0',   '8.14.0',   '8.14.1',  '8.15.0',  '8.15.1',
  '8.16.0',   '8.16.1',   '8.16.2',   '8.17.0',  '9.0.0',   '9.1.0',
  '9.2.0',    '9.3.0',    '9.4.0',    '9.5.0',   '9.6.0',   '9.6.1',
  '9.7.0',    '9.8.0',    '9.9.0',    '9.10.0',  '9.10.1',  '9.11.0',
  '9.11.2',   '10.0.0',   '10.1.0',   '10.2.0',  '10.3.0',  '10.4.0',
  '10.4.1',   '10.5.0',   '10.6.0',   '10.7.0',  '10.8.0',  '10.9.0',
  '10.10.0',  '10.11.0',  '10.12.0',  '10.13.0', '10.14.0', '10.14.1',
  '10.14.2',  '10.15.0',  '10.15.1',  '10.15.2', '10.15.3', '10.16.0',
  '10.16.1',  '10.16.2',  '10.16.3',  '10.17.0', '10.18.0', '10.18.1',
  '10.19.0',  '10.20.0',  '10.20.1',  '10.21.0', '10.22.0', '10.22.1',
  '10.23.0',  '10.23.2',  '10.24.0',  '10.24.1', '11.0.0',  '11.1.0',
  '11.2.0',   '11.3.0',   '11.4.0',   '11.5.0',  '11.6.0',  '11.7.0',
  '11.8.0',   '11.9.0',   '11.10.0',  '11.11.0', '11.12.0', '11.13.0',
  '11.14.0',  '11.15.0',  '12.0.0',   '12.1.0',  '12.2.0',  '12.3.0',
  '12.3.1',   '12.4.0',   '12.5.0',   '12.6.0',  '12.7.0',  '12.8.0',
  '12.8.1',   '12.9.0',   '12.9.1',   '12.10.0', '12.11.0', '12.11.1',
  '12.12.0',  '12.13.0',  '12.13.1',  '12.14.0', '12.14.1', '12.15.0',
  '12.16.0',  '12.16.1',  '12.16.2',  '12.16.3', '12.17.0', '12.18.0',
  '12.18.1',  '12.18.2',  '12.18.3',  '12.18.4', '12.19.0', '12.19.1',
  '12.20.0',  '12.20.1',  '12.21.0',  '12.22.1', '12.22.2', '12.22.3',
  '12.22.4',  '12.22.5',  '12.22.6',  '12.22.7', '12.22.8', '12.22.9',
  '12.22.10', '12.22.11', '12.22.12', '13.0.0',  '13.0.1',  '13.1.0',
  '13.2.0',   '13.3.0',   '13.4.0',   '13.5.0',  '13.6.0',  '13.7.0',
  '13.8.0',   '13.9.0',   '13.10.0',  '13.10.1', '13.11.0', '13.12.0',
  '13.13.0',  '13.14.0',  '14.0.0',   '14.1.0',  '14.2.0',  '14.3.0',
  '14.4.0',   '14.5.0',   '14.6.0',   '14.7.0',  '14.8.0',  '14.9.0',
  '14.10.0',  '14.10.1',  '14.11.0',  '14.12.0', '14.13.0', '14.13.1',
  '14.14.0',  '14.15.0',  '14.15.1',  '14.15.2', '14.16.0', '14.16.1',
  '14.17.1',  '14.17.2',  '14.17.3',  '14.17.4', '14.17.5', '14.17.6',
  '14.18.0',  '14.18.1',  '14.18.2',  '14.18.3', '14.19.0', '14.19.1',
  '14.19.2',  '14.19.3',  '14.20.0',  '14.20.1', '14.21.0', '14.21.2',
  '14.21.3',  '15.0.0',   '15.0.1',   '15.1.0',  '15.2.0',  '15.2.1',
  '15.3.0',   '15.4.0',   '15.7.0',   '15.8.0',  '15.10.0', '15.12.0',
  '15.14.0',  '16.0.0',   '16.1.0',   '16.3.0',  '16.4.0',  '16.4.1',
  '16.5.0',   '16.6.0',   '16.6.1',   '16.6.2',  '16.7.0',  '16.8.0',
  '16.9.0',   '16.9.1',   '16.10.0',  '16.11.0', '16.11.1', '16.12.0',
  '16.13.0',  '16.13.1',  '16.13.2',  '16.14.0', '16.14.1', '16.14.2',
  '16.15.0',  '16.15.1',  '16.16.0',  '16.17.0', '16.17.1', '16.18.0',
  '16.18.1',  '16.19.0',  '16.19.1',  '16.20.0', '16.20.1', '16.20.2',
  '17.0.0',   '17.0.1',   '17.1.0',   '17.2.0',  '17.3.0',  '17.3.1',
  '17.4.0',   '17.5.0',   '17.6.0',   '17.7.0',  '17.7.1',  '17.7.2',
  '17.9.1',   '18.0.0',   '18.1.0',   '18.2.0',  '18.3.0',  '18.4.0',
  '18.5.0',   '18.6.0',   '18.7.0',   '18.8.0',  '18.9.0',  '18.9.1',
  '18.10.0',  '18.11.0',  '18.12.0',  '18.12.1', '18.13.0', '18.14.0',
  '18.14.1',  '18.14.2',  '18.15.0',  '18.16.0', '18.16.1', '18.17.0',
  '18.17.1',  '19.0.0',   '19.0.1',   '19.1.0',  '19.2.0',  '19.3.0',
  '19.4.0',   '19.5.0',   '19.6.0',   '19.6.1',  '19.7.0',  '19.8.0',
  '19.8.1',   '20.0.0',   '20.1.0',   '20.2.0',  '20.3.0',  '20.3.1',
  '20.4.0',   '20.5.0',   '20.5.1'
]
```

As long as i can't install the correct version of node, i can't build my project. So your helps are appreciated. ***And to be honest, i am kinda beginner on linux.***

Thank you

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48910876/error-eacces-permission-denied-access-usr-local-lib-node-modules/60354084

Answer (score 0):

- To resolve this issue you need to run the command as a sudo user, so just add `sudo`
- It is recommended to use NVM to upgrade/switch node versions